# How can I access nested json in supabase using sql and http_get()?

Tags: sql, json, http, plpgsql, supabase

**Disclaimer**: This is my first time working with any  kind of backend database.

## The problem

I have been trying for days now to get and return data from nested json using plpgsql in supabase. So far, no success.

- Here is the json url: https://citiusmag.com/_next/data/SDV7SU9r0GNcSnNu-5KTY/articles.json
- Yes, the http extension is enabled in supabase.

Ultimately, I want to be able to get the title, url, and some other information from each article in the json object. Once I have that, add it to an existing supabase table as text. The function below was my first attempt at getting nested JSON. If I can't do this, I can't do the later steps.

## What I've tried so far

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_story()
RETURNS text AS $$

DECLARE
    response text;
    json_data jsonb;
    json_path text[] := array['pageProps', 'articles', '0', 'title'];

BEGIN
  response := http_get('https://citiusmag.com/_next/data/u2nS96606xMsi5BHSXWG1/articles.json');
  json_data := response::jsonb;
  return json_data #>> json_path;

END; $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT get_story()
```

...and many variations of this.

## Notes:

- I've accessed the github repo (https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http#functions) and so far I've not been able to use/understand enough to help me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you double check your JSON URL? I'm seeing a website when I access it.